# node with multiple images attached (drupal 6.x)

Tags: drupal, module, slideshow

I'm creating a site where user can create a node with multiple images attached. For that matter, I have installed image attach module. I also have view and view slideshow module installed so that user can see the uploaded images attached to this particular node in slideshow style.

The problem I'm facing right now is that view does not show all the images attached to this particular node. It shows one image only and that's it.

The way I set up the view is - I create it as a block, select "image attach" for Fields and choose node id for argument. Under the node id, I choose "node id from url" for default argument. The result is just only one image being shown.

I've been trying to figure out what I'm missing and, so far I found out that image_attach 
table stores images attached to the same node with same nid. And the view query is returning only one. I appreciate much if anyone of you can point me to right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems okay except one major thing -- the use of Image Attach ! Consider using Imagefield ( http://drupal.org/project/imagefield ) with Imagecache modules ( http://drupal.org/project/imagecache ). They work really well with Views and Views Slideshow in particular. Imagefield+Imagecache is really the standard way images are now done in Drupal. Its also the default approach for images in Drupal 7.

There is plenty of documentation available about this approach.

Comment: Here are some tutorials to get you started: http://www.drupaltherapy.com/imagecache http://blip.tv/file/316842 (Imagecache+Imagefield). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWJY4K7uDp0 (Views Slideshow)

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem and I use these modules. The slideshow should only take images from one node (which frustratingly only displays 1 image), or if I remove the limit it shows all images, but from all the nodes! Suggestions?!